# Laplace Transform

Tags: laplace-transform

How can one show that 1/$e^s$  is not the laplace transform of any function?

Note that function here does not include distributions like dirac delta function.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that $e^{-s}$ is the Laplace transform of some function $f(t)$. Then, $$f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \lim_{T \to \infty} \int_{\gamma -iT}^{\gamma+iT} e^{st}e^{-s}\ ds = \delta(t-1).$$

By uniqueness of the inverse Laplace transform, this is the only such "function."

Comment: Which uniqueness theorem do you use here? I know that uniqeness follows from the Bernstein theorem, which is not studied in standard analysis courses

Comment: @Nimza The presumption was that $e^{-s}$ was the Laplace transform of a function, so the uniqueness comes from the assumption of existence of a prior that had a Laplace transform of $e^{-s}$. So the conditions of continuity, etc. in the time-domain function are presumed, and then we use linearity.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since $\hat{f}(s) = e^{-s} \implies f(t) = \delta(t-1)$, then, yes, there is no non-distribution function that is the ILT of $\hat{f}(s) = e^{-s}$.